# TS: Infer literal typing based on chained methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is only one thing left for me to unblock my flow and publish the first trial version of my form validation lib.

I have the following code (of course I'm omitting a lot of things so it doesn't get too big)

```
interface Validation {
  name: string
  message: string
  params?: Record<string, any>
  test: (value: any, params?: any) => boolean
}

class MixedSchema<T> {
  type!: T
  validations: Validation[] = []

  required(message?: string) {
    this.validations.push({
      name: 'required',
      message: message,
      test: (value: any) => {
        return value === '' ? false : true
      },
    })

    return this
  }

  oneOf(arrayOfValues: any[], message?: string) {
    type Params = { arrayOfValues: any[] }

    this.validations.push({
      name: 'oneOf',
      params: { arrayOfValues },
      message: message,
      test: (value: any, params: Params) => {
        return params.arrayOfValues.includes(value)
      },
    })

    return this
  }
}

class StringSchema extends MixedSchema<string> {
  email() {
    // this.validations.push({ ... })
    return this
  }

  maxWords(maxWords: number, message?: string) {
    // this.validations.push({ ... })
    return this
  }
}

class NumberSchema extends MixedSchema<number> {
  min(min: number, message?: string) {
    // this.validations.push({ ... })
    return this
  }

  round(type: 'toUp' | 'toDown' | 'closer') {
    // this.validations.push({ ... })
    return this
  }
}

const schema = {
  string() {
    return new StringSchema()
  },
  number() {
    return new NumberSchema()
  },
  // array, file, etc..
}

const form = {
  email: schema.string().required(),
  age: schema.number().min(18),
  gender: schema.string().oneOf(['male', 'female']).required(),
  color: schema.string().oneOf(['red', 'blue', 'green']),
}

type InferType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends MixedSchema<infer TS> ? TS : never
}

type Form = InferType<typeof form>
```

So I get the following result

[image]

But I need to get the most real typing possible, I mean, similar to the schema defined for `form`, example

```
interface HowNeedsToBe {
  email: string
  age: number | undefined
  gender: 'male' | 'female'
  color: 'red' | 'blue' | 'green' | undefined
}
```

I believe that the logic is something like, in the absence of the `required`, puts an `undefined` and if there is `oneOf`, substitutes the argument with the `T` of the `MixedSchema<T>`, but I don’t know how to send this back to up to `MixedSchema<T>`, actually I think this logic is a mess.

I already researched about map and generics in typescript, but I confess that when it comes to putting it into practice, nothing good comes out.

Here's the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexGQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwuTqabnYbNWHLgAc4UWkwD8jAEoQEBKNgA8LNiHYAaZHBABPAHxdILRgAoAbpgCug-Qd3jJNGY0cBKZAF4jyACMCAgwIfTIAXzIyBAw4XmQAWWAADwhsAGUEAAsIGjhVABV-ckowA1EIAEJGQq4bLFx8IiZGdEa8QhAAbQBdX2Q+6MooCABHW2BR7AsePgFZIU12b1LKZDBs4CYAOgacTpad0VsmbIs19apaQQByUYmp9NvtLiu5-kEPgWQAH1-kLcdjsXm91mYwJYGvYPIZvH5SGCrqMwLYoMRoSgfNjAbdkNJkPAMEwUIxWPYkcgIq8rhFPMN1ii0cRNtsuFEuEQIAB5GAWCSSAy89r2Vp6Qx9XTfCCLDQcVZg8qVZAABQkUgGJD0UEFwrsEDFjj6VIZZS2u32TS6uxOZwulOodEYty5vNBV0oLikjC1ArgQpgIoNVJpHuljGlfwBQJBoauEKh+thTmQXrcjDVriY8JKlJGEFR6NT6rcOz9AaDu1AsVs2AN1n19I9IbBdNNyCZRdZTHZkWisXiTGQGWEWiyuXyyAgKUgIGwQ+SaUyOTyBTlWlzlFXwAwFgVVwA9AeNua9pgDs0QDbTuctcCdlSm4yC8yT2zKBzKPkUgB1ZTz2Y4F-f8xRAWwaACaApQNeYZUYdcVkRQ9j27M8Okva87TvYFHzBTsWXNXsOQHBIADlwMgqBx1XKcZwgOcF1SdJqPyVQwIg6BN24UBZlARh2Mo6DeE+WVR0Qy5kCPN8LXPK0jltW9kHvXDkRfLtCI-BkoAIWw5wsJU7jAAgAFVRDxaMjIAEQIAB3EBzMBWICBJKBbn3dYpNQy1DivY4bwuJScLbVTCwI98TWIlowGYFdJx8JClg4PcEvzUKqAgGzhzEli4D3dlQwE6Bkok-D0sy8iOKo2LcqfakuCk8tdBgHcIF0AsEGBPsYiiwllBoTUuG3DB4OqnYEL3HYHkmaY91DT4RonOAdkKqAJpoHiAEYAA5PFDAQ52gBbVzGsSJtdPlulufJQheQEYFXG7ek8Sbxmm9JZq4JQMGUI78hO5YzpAHkLvuZ5dFuAIMHsW7bnYUZ6NuJ7Xg5AzkAASRAe6oEKCoICKfx4rWboVWQUBkAAawgAwCBgZBCl6Wpif6adZ3nJImOXRbVFALG6YyfwCUKDJkH4iArGgLrUYAMT6gYMaxnHKlUAyad6qAaBMMhQEgWBEBQAAJWzSIgdImEKAgACEUDWIb4LErh5qoCjoD+ZBdLrZqgewLh9rrKBnWuiAHNue7A9uT6Qh+wFpmDyHodd2H4fs133YgT30kiIA) if you want to try.

Comment: Just use something like `oneOf<U extends T>(arrayOfValues: U[]): MixedSchema<U>` (or maybe `this & MixedSchema<U>`). Try to get rid of *all* the `any`s in your code.

Comment: I wish `this & MixedSchema<U>` would work, but I don't think it does the right things in general.  The subclassing makes me want [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) but TS doesn't have it, so it has to be simulated; blah

Comment: @Bergi this works well, now all that’s missing is some kind of condition to infer the kind `| undefined`

Comment: @Bergi I noticed that you like to comment and it helps me a lot, but if I could add an answer I could mark it as a solution and that way it would not be an unsolved post, but with a solution to help other people in the future

Comment: @YungSilva It was only a guess, as jcalz (who knows more about TypeScript than me) confirms it actually doesn't work.

Comment: @YungSilva do you not care that after you use `oneOf()` on a `StringSchema` you won't be able to call `email()` anymore?  Or if you can call it, that it then forgets about the narrowing?  [This](https://tsplay.dev/Wyv1gw) is what I have to do to give you "the right" narrowings, but if you don't care, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/W440BW) works.  But you should test them out.  I'm happy to write up an answer but I don't want to step on any toes; let me know if one of those is what you want.

Comment: @jcalz writing an answer never steps on anyone's toes (except maybe when the question is an obvious duplicate)

Comment: @jcalz the first link with `Specialize` type works fine, just added `(): Specialize<this, U | undefined>` as return from `oneOf` so that it seals inferred `undefined` and obtains [this result](https://i.ibb.co/5LWW9Fd/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-20-a-s-18-08-50.png). here is [the final result](https://tsplay.dev/WzyKEm), if you have nothing more to add, you could put it as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution, thank you for all your help!

Comment: I will write an answer when I get a chance, but right now I’m not available to do it.  If someone else does it first, c’est la vie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually you want the `required()` and `oneOf()` methods to narrow `T`; this would be easy enough to give types to (although you need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to avoid compiler errors, since the compiler can't verify that you have actually done the requisite narrowing).  So `required()`, called on a `MixedSchema<T>`, should return a `MixedSchema<Exclude<T, undefined>>` (using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to remove `undefined` from any union members of `T`).  And `oneOf()` should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the element type `U` of the elements of `arrayOfValues`, and should return a `MixedSchema<U | Extract<undefined, T>>` (using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to keep `undefined` if the `T` can be `undefined`).

Here's how it might look (implementations elided for brevity):

```
declare class MixedSchema<T> {
  type: T
  validations: Validation[];
  required(message?: string): MixedSchema<Exclude<T, undefined>>;
  oneOf<U extends T>(arrayOfValues: U[], message?: string): 
    MixedSchema<U | Extract<undefined, T>>
}
```

Unfortunately the fact that you are subclassing `MixedSchema` is complicating matters; you want to say that, for example, a `StringSchema` should stay a `StringSchema` of some kind after calling `required()`; it should not be widened back to `MixedSchema`:

```
declare class StringSchema<T extends string | undefined> extends MixedSchema<T> {
  email(): this;
  maxWords(maxWords: number, message?: string): this;
}

declare class NumberSchema<T extends number | undefined> extends MixedSchema<T> {
  min(min: number, message?: string): this;
  round(type: 'toUp' | 'toDown' | 'closer'): this;
}

const s = new StringSchema() // StringSchema<string | undefined>
s.email(); // okay
const t = s.required(); // MixedSchema<string>
t.email(); // error! Property 'email' does not exist on type 'MixedSchema<string>';
```

So we will need something more complicated.

---

The "right" answer here is to use so-called *higher-kinded types* of the sort requested (but not implemented) in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  You'd like to say something like: `MixedSchema<T>`'s `required()` method should return `this<Exclude<T, undefined>>`, where you are somehow treating `this` like a type that takes a generic parameter.  So if `this` is a `StringSchema<T>`, then it should be `StringSchema<Exclude<T, undefined>>`.  But there's no direct support for this.

Instead we need to simulate it, and all such simulations will involve some amount of "registering" the types we'd like to be able to treat like a generic-of-a-generic:

```
type Specify<C extends MixedSchema<any>, T> =
  C extends NumberSchema<any> ? NumberSchema<Extract<T, number | undefined>> :
  C extends StringSchema<any> ? StringSchema<Extract<T, string | undefined>> :
  MixedSchema<T>;
```

We've listed out all the subclasses of `MixedSchema` that we care about and described how to specify their type parameters.  So while we can't write `this<Exclude<T, undefined>>`, but we *can* write `Specify<this, Exclude<T, undefined>>` and have the same effect.

Here's the new implementation of `MixedSchema`:

```
declare class MixedSchema<T> {
  type: T
  validations: Validation[];
  required(message?: string): Specify<this, Exclude<T, undefined>>;
  oneOf<U extends T>(arrayOfValues: U[], message?: string): 
    Specify<this, U | Extract<undefined, T>>
}
```

And we can verify that it now behaves appropriately in subclasses:

```
const s = new StringSchema() // StringSchema<string | undefined>
s.email(); // okay
const t = s.required(); // StringSchema<string>
t.email(); // okay
```

---

Let's make sure that the types are inferred as you'd like:

```
const form = {
  email: schema.string().required(),
  age: schema.number().min(18),
  gender: schema.string().oneOf(['male', 'female']).required(),
  color: schema.string().oneOf(['red', 'blue', 'green']),
}
/* const form: {
    email: StringSchema<string>;
    age: NumberSchema<number | undefined>;
    gender: StringSchema<"male" | "female">;
    color: StringSchema<"red" | "blue" | "green" | undefined>;
} */
```

That's a good sign; the generic type parameter for each field has been specified the right way.  And thus your `InferType` should be able to grab those fields types:

```
type Form = InferType<typeof form>
/* type Form = {
    email: string;
    age: number | undefined;
    gender: "male" | "female";
    color: "red" | "blue" | "green" | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexGQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwuTqabnYbNWHLgAc4UWkwD8jAEoQEBKNgA8LNiHYAaZHBABPAHxdILRgAoAbpgCug-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-q0ZqocB0JQL2UAAITIAACr2AxQH0yDDv+U7YAQgZUAQMEwjaMFEL0-QoMOeq3Fhr7nEYw5rNE+6xIG8QoHUwA0LYhSQAAEgA0u0CLkKYgmXgMCDADABiqAAwkW8oiS+jhGFy-g+OsllasWibJtAtmGP40jIEmOapgajywpICAsu0uiNrm9L5l+-j0M5VklleHBecYyC+SlEpBaojKheFug4e+7Lqv8yAJUCNk5Z00kxoKmzCqUurkqJUqVusg6DOsow4HMkzTJgvUTIsqw9tsuz7IcgbHISbahqSdRGSZZkRkwuhPC8bwRcqH4FhqALrCCYI0q58pIiiEHonYgaMDiSzNjNIbnAtS2maoq26FC9J5cyrK7RyDnftGyACoUDXxk+17VUlCJFTF-2lTDGGtYaXQmoRAHhl2drVu6zoqEwboegTDYeVAD3BnNz1Y7uvLRHVYPFE1flky+7RI1FUDFZ+iOnSWVVie1QI1iAdYgKTAUU62CodjT3ZAr2-adSOY4TiuTFjvOS7q2uGAbluO7y8g+6UIex4Ij4Z4Xll7A3t46E2y+cM7SVfxcPB-7EehYEQVBR4wTBlvwYhE0oYBJGOzlOF4QRcBEeH3vgZBMnROhBh9sgC5mhgZ61L0XbIM0GD0QJAzAlzTAEHQEZaMgWCgSgwABwQ3BwA3yqiMgMDKPnKCFAgoHAjAyBae0w4IqAiJ1GQnWGYoy0WUjAtSnZDm+FwLmyvK-kpmlPkswFL4-WF7xUGT3N7WVFXIJvmaQ6lOV2Rl9-ZWJx8FTL7AX3F5VcMvqPSQhv-CsaNKCdQoowIYIxBrjHmFiGYQ15jLFPMsemGxxrIQOPiaWOEXrzzeh9BkzwMCvAgKfWKpVQE9FWj+HqsDJg-lELYJgjQLBVh6HJEcIdMHDm0Osas00CSMGwSgWkq4fw-l4fw3ogYwCWFGPYDwhhvB+GNECBWEAwC2CgMQBRKAfAGKYlOXy8AMCbnKr0KA9hpERD4UCCIngxpaJ0fnG0egESOCjGgo64IoR8wROdMil0YAYhutiXE3BBE4PmowRa+CVpdk+kqd+f1XackRGVdhs9qISCkKeEgegglohCddLEjhkHAzAV2WhMC+pHkYcw1h7DKCcKYj4qR6jkAuCkIwApF1imhIRLY6RIjhFRNEeIyRdj1FmDkcgaw10lFOC6bktwjAcmuCYCoqhnTNjOOIN0twP5+lXRIYGH8oBNqBgWWcxxnThn2McU47RxBVruL0IYLxfIIaR0FkjZ2FDCz+ORmzKhntvDsPQjQuhdT4JMJYWw5AEifzGzuT0PZLzXFMD3Ggh0+NXR4s9BLJskSWyzU-hC9YULqkwuGnCxpiLkWoueS41aOLvnMx3p5aGwLObf15lvfmLVQVqO4LWEWxL-SkselTEkorKDUptDU2YdKGkIoKUyhxLLXldhxVwRWXwByCRVuOSc05NaLmXNOdcm4oDbnlSRaFtTVXwqaUiiRzKNH7Kxey6IZsYJMCCvk92oZbzsIxS47I1tnxBQtHuaZnMw3aqtgfXesa0UPJIv03QPxQi6E0QgCRkQ-XQS7soGgwbKD-jbEFH8OELQIQwZNTw0yhHMFrYmzwP4RYWAAIwAA4W1cAEB+KANasJ1tDV2nxFgFjDlaKEXhTEYD3EXUsLt3Dm3TKUHrMd7aJ31undkMEs7hz7CXcOAIZyL3sE2HKYc66+FRDvAAKmFKW7uUAaC9PRnHDAsSY1iWjjjPQAhGBcsCmJPl8M0kHSBCO-Ie7flSgAEQLogChpUKGV3oZQ3BnoO7lAAahmJFD+xMP0hQ1e+wFHkAodvRAOUtHAUajWBEZAL67zRFngASRACuqA7RBIdEcqKhY1FkCTwbunYe7QliQPE0sJewqcqgAE1Pfe7Q6gWOyFYaAxaZ4GQAGLltPHxgTQmBjvUEgQYen6aAmFfaXFAJmv2Vp6NWz+IG23QZdjzWoIGEPQEYGhzAGGsM4bCyhkDhG91kdqLRqjZzEsMaY-ygLkQONcaAA)

Comment: Best impossible answer, thanks for your dedicated time and for explaining each part, I appreciate that.